# System.json.text in not found in JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CarCounter>>(json)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I have an azure function and the code look like this. I use .Net 6

```
   [FunctionName("CarCounterFunc")]
    public void Run(
        [BlobTrigger("input/{name}.xml")] Stream inputBlob,IBinder binder,string
        name,ILogger log)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(inputBlob);

        string json = jsonHandling.Convert(doc);
        json = jsonHandling.Clean(json);

        List<CarCounter> myList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CarCounter>>(json);
    }
```

As soon as I add this row

```cs
List<CarCounter> myList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CarCounter>>(json);
```

I get these error

```
[2023-05-15T16:07:48.680Z] Executing 'CarCounterFunc' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): input/a9909523-a23b-47ed-9732-40ea4535c82f.xml', Id=68bf0483-5f36-4325-8d82-01e02c0b3361)
[2023-05-15T16:07:48.689Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: b427a04e-620b-44db-8948-d5d9cc25145a, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2023-05-15T16:07:47.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2023-05-15T16:07:46.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2023-05-15T16:07:46.000+00:00
[2023-05-15T16:07:48.955Z] Executed 'CarCounterFunc' (Failed, Id=68bf0483-5f36-4325-8d82-01e02c0b3361, Duration=627ms)
[2023-05-15T16:07:48.957Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: CarCounterFunc. CarCounterprj: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Det går inte att hitta filen.
```

Many thanks in advance
Tony Johansson

Comment: Code is not finding "'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0".  I would do a clean build.  I suspect you updated the version of Net/Core and didn't rebuild the application.  If you still have an error than from Solution Explorer delete the Reference System.Text.Json. and then add again to you are using the version of the library that is installed on your machine.

Comment: runc this commnad in the package manager console NuGet\Install-Package System.Text.Json -Version 7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I received the same error as you get when I installed `System.Text.Json` package.

[image]

[image]

But After I uninstalled the package I could able to make this work. This is because the version .NetCore 3.0 and above have inbuilt packages installed which includes `System.Text.Json`. For more information, You can refer [Announcing .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0/#introducing-a-fast-json-api) by Rich Lander. For demonstration purposes, I used a sample JSON directly. Below is the complete code that worked for me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp16
{

    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("container/{name}", Connection = "constr")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

            string json1 = @"[{ ""Name"": ""John"", ""Age"": ""30"" }]";

            List<CarCounter> carCounterList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CarCounter>>(json1);

            foreach (CarCounter carCounter in carCounterList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {carCounter.Name}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Age: {carCounter.Age}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]